# How to pass params into the soap request

Tags: go, http, soap

I have an example how a request looks like:

```
POST /DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.cbr.ru
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://web.cbr.ru/GetCursOnDateXML"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCursOnDateXML xmlns="http://web.cbr.ru/">
      <On_date>dateTime</On_date>
    </GetCursOnDateXML>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I wrote some code to make this request:

```
func main() {

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx", strings.NewReader("the body"))
    req.Method = "POST"
    fmt.Println(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Length", "length")
    req.Header.Add("SOAPAction", "http://web.cbr.ru/GetCursOnDateXML")
    req.Host = "www.cbr.ru"
    client := http.Client{}
// code
}
```

But I don't know how to pass params into the request which follows after name of param (I mean "On_date")

How can I do it? I've never made requests like this. Thank you in advance!

PS If there're any mistakes in my code please notify me